# breath technique during jogging

Tags: jogging, breathing

I'm jogging for everyday. i use to get stopped by myself due to high breathing though i jogging in good pace.

How to improve and keep it steady my jog and is that good to drink water after / before jogging?

Answer (score 0):

A good breathing exercise to slow down your breathing is to time your breathing with your steps. Inhale for three steps then exhale for two. "Steps" in this case would be for one foot. If you chose your left foot, the pattern would be:

Inhale:

- Left
- Right
- Left
- Right
- Left

Exhale:

- Left
- Right
- Left

This would mean that the faster you run, the faster you breath, and the slower you run the slower you breath.  If you focus on this for enough time, you should eventually just start doing it automatically.

You can drink water any time. Although drinking *a lot* of water before a jog may cause minor stomach pain. I've personally never had a problem with it, but I know people who have. I would say it's an absolute requirement to drink water before and during a jog on hot days.

Answer (score 0):

A good breathing exercise you should consider during jogging is to close your mouth during the process. Though there has been studies to suggest that it doesn't matter if you breath through your nose or mouth, i am a strong advocate for nasal breathing during run/jogging. The reason is that, when you breath through your nose, it forces you to breath from your stomach and causes you to be more calm as it slows your breathing down. I always run this way and i can run forever and not feel like i'm running out of breath but the minute i open my mouth, i feel like my chest gets hit with too much air. My suggestion for you is to close your mouth while running and perform  the left right breathing exercise suggested in Answer1 by @DeeV and see how it works for you. Try to hydrate hours before you run. It's always better to be hydrated hours before the run than to try to hydrate during run. Lesson: stay hydrated all the time so that when ever you feel like running, you will be good to go.